# When buying and playing a Villa in Dominion do you in a sense get 3 buys for that turn?

Tags: dominion, dominion-empires

So I buy a [Villa](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Villa) in my buy phase (buy #1), then I go back to my action phase. I play Villa and follow it with 2 actions, then proceed to my second buy phase with +1 treasure +1 buy (buy #2) from the Villa. As I go into this second buy phase do I get another free buy as I just started a new buy phase (buy #3)?

Answer (score 12):

You don't get a new free Buy, sorry. Nice thinking though.

The base game rules do say that when you enter a Buy phase you get one default Buy, but the card-specific notes for the Villa in the Empires rules (page 11) clarify (or revise?) that you only get one default Buy in the entire turn, not one each buy phase:

> If you buy Villa, that uses up your default Buy for the turn, however playing Villa will give you +1 Buy and so let you buy another card in your second Buy phase.

Another way to think about it might be that the game gives you +1 Buy as you start your turn, but not each Buy phase as the base rules might imply.

Once you re-enter the Buy phase you will have 1 Buy left from Villa itself, in addition to whatever other action cards you've played this turn, but not 1 free Buy from the game. From what you described you only have 2 Buys this turn.

Comment: That’s what I thought. My wife argued that she got a new buy each buy phase and therefore got 3 buys. She got pissed off when I stated that I really don’t think she was right. Thanks for clarifying!